# Web Part Not Showing In Add Web Parts Dialog

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I created a couple of web parts using the Visual Studio 2008 SharePoint Web Part template. However, when I deploy it says everything has deployed successfully but, when I try to add the web parts they are not available in the add web part dialog from within my portal...

Any thoughts..? I did this with another web part project and didn't have this issue...

The only difference I see is that this project has two web parts in it and the other had one...

Answer (score 1):

There should be a feature for the solution.  VSeWSS normally activates the feature, but it is possible that it didn't get activated.  I would check the list of features, it should be fairly obvious which is yours and whether or not it has been activated.

Comment: where should I check to see if the feature is installed..? In the 12 hive..?

Comment: Site Actions > Site Features

Check to see if they exist at all, and then check to see if they are "Active"

Answer (score 1):

Check if your web part is defined as public (Public in VB)

internal is default (Friend in VB)

this is *the* classic mistake to make here :-)

Anders Rask

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I have had, during a manual install of the webpart, was that there was an error with the webpart that was not picked up in the developement environment. Check the ULS logs for when the feature was activated and see if there is an error there that says why the webpart is not showing up.